# Understanding a proposition about $\mathcal R$-section in ordered sets (VERY EDITED)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The correct title must be: **Proof of Theorem 90 of Appendix of Kelley's book *General Topology*** or, **Proving a theorem about $\mathcal R$-sections** or **Prove of this prove that proof aboutTheorem 90 of Appendix of Kelley's book *General Topology*** .

**Proposition.** Let $(X,\mathcal R)$ be an ordered set (or class). If $Y\subset X$ is an $\mathcal R$-section and every element $y\in Y$ is also an $\mathcal R$-section of $X$, then $\bigcup Y$ and $\bigcap Y$ are $\mathcal R$-sections of $X$.

EDIT 1: The statement was misunderstood by me. The real porposition is:

> > Let $I$ non-empty (possibly $I$ is a set). If every element $y\in I$ is an $\mathcal R$-section of $X$, then $\bigcup I$ and $\bigcap I$ are also.

So the comment of @WilliamElliot is unnecesary, because in any momment we have said $I\subset X$. And probably it may be false. In my opinion, $I$ plays the role of an index set.

**Addendum 1.** This statement corresponds to the Appendix of J. L. Kelley *General Topology*, Theorem 90 (p. 264).

EDIT 2: Below is the rest of my question. Whit the new remarks it has no sense.
My problem is that I can't understand why (or how) an element $y\in Y$ can be an $\mathcal R$-section of $X$ if $y$ is not a subset of $X$ (as least as far as I know). It would have sense for me if the text said $\{y\}$, which is actually a subset of $X$.

The same applies to $\bigcup Y$ and $\bigcap Y$: by DEFINITION, both are sets (classes) formed by elements of sets in $Y$:

$$
\bigcup Y= \{x:\exists y\in Y \mbox{ such that } x\in y\}\\
\bigcap Y= \{x|x\in y \;\forall y\in Y\}.
$$

Again, to be an $\mathcal R$-section, we should consider $\{\bigcup Y\}$ and $\{\bigcap Y\}$.

**Addendum 2. (Real questions)** Once I have understood the proposition, the result seems me evident. However, I don't know how how to prove it rigorously. I know I have a collection of sets $\{y:y\in I\}$ such that

$$ \mbox{if } y_1,y_2\in Y \mbox{ with } y_1\neq y_2 \Longrightarrow y_1\subset y_2 \mbox{ or } y_2\subset y_1 , $$

So I actually have a descendent chain of sets

$$ y\supset y' \supset y'' \supset \cdots $$

1.- Proof for $\bigcup I$. With the above in mind, I think $bigcup I = y$ which is an $\mathcal R$-section by hypothesis.

2.- Proof for $\bigcap I$. I think the definition of $\mathcal R$-section avoids there is some $y\in I$ such that $y=\emptyset$. So I think all them has a common element, the least element $y_0$, and thus $\bigcap I$ is non-empty. Now, let $x\in X$ and $y\in\bigcap I$ with $x\mathcal R y$ and suppose $x\notin \bigcap I$. That implies that $x$ is less than the least element $y_0$. But then, $x$ wouldn't below either to $y\in I$, which is a contradiction, because $y$ was an $\mathcal R$-section$. So $\bigcap I$ is an $\mathcal R$-section.

Questions about this proof:

1.- Is the proof of $bigcup I$ correct?

2.- Is the proof of $\bigcap I$ correct?

3.- In 2., do you think I need to proove $y_0\in \bigcap I$? Is there a shorter proof?

4.- If all the inclusions are proper, then is it possible to show that $\bigcap I=\{y_0\}$?

**Definition.** Let $\mathcal R$ be a well-order in $X$. An $\mathcal R$-section is $Y\subset X$ such that if $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ with $x\mathcal R y$, then $x\in Y$.

Informally, a set (class) $Y$ is said to be an $\mathcal R$-section if there is no element in $X\setminus Y$ that precedes the elements of $Y$.

**Final Remark.** I have prefered keep the old question and add the edits and corrections, because I think that is more proper. Sorry if it is a bad idea.

Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of typos here. And what is a $\mathcal{R}$-section of an ordered set $(X,\mathcal{R})$?

Comment: @amrsa: See the edit

Comment: Take at look at the construction of the ordinals.  0 is empty, 1 = {0}, 2 = {0,1}, 3 = {0,1,2}, etc.

Comment: So a section is what is otherwise called an [order-ideal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialOrderIdeal.html); notice however that in Wikipedia, [Ideal (order theory)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(order_theory)) requires more conditions.

Comment: I also think you should see if William Elliot's suggestion applies (this depends on the context of in which it is being used). I don't like this kind of language abuse (although it makes perfect sense when studying ordinals), but perhaps $y$ is, in this context supposed to mean $\{x \in X : x \leq y\}$, or similar...

Comment: @WilliamElliot: I don't understand why you want to say me. $0$ is not a subset of $1$, even $0\in 1$, that is true :|

Comment: @amrsa: If you give some extra interpretation to the $y$ notation perfect. In fact I suppose the author does it. What I wanted was to know if the literal statement of the theorem was true. If you add some extra notations I'm sure it is true. On the hand, now the problem would be find the corrct interpretation, but that is another story...

Comment: @Dog_69.  For the 0 and 1 that I defined, 0 is both a subset of 1 and an element in 1.  Consider the 2-section, namely {0,1} .

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Yes, you're right. In fact, I don't know what I was thinking about. $\emptyset$ is always subset. And if I'm not wrong, $\bigcup\{0,1\}$ is $\emptyset=0$, which is a section I supposed. But $\bigcup\{0,1\}$.. could it be $1=\{\emptyset\}$? But in this case the proposition would be false... I don't know :(

Comment: @Dog_69 ⋃{0,1} = 0 $\cup$ 1 = 1

Comment: In my above I comment, I would like to say $\bigcap\{0,1\}=\emptyset = 0$, sorry. And for $\bigcup\{0,1\}$, the proposition still bieng true, since $0<1$ but it is true that $0\in1$. Agg, it is very strange. I extpected that in natural numbers, the sections would be $\{0,1,2,\dots,n\}$ for any $n$, but not that $1$ may be a section.

Comment: Dear sirs, look at my renewed question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the notations in the book have been misunderstood. I have the 1964 edition, in which the theorem is,

**$90$ THEOREM** If $n\not=0$ and each member of $n$ is an $r$-section of $x$ , then $\bigcup n$ and $\bigcap n$ are $r$-sections of $x$.

Here $0$ is the void class, and $n$ is a class-of-classes; this may be understood from the definition of the union $\bigcup$ and the intersection $\bigcap$ operators.

Let $n=\{\{1,2\},\{1,2,5\},\{1,2,3,4,5\} \}$. Then, $\bigcup n=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\bigcap n = \{1,2\}$.

In this sense, the theorem can be reworded in terms of ordinary set theory as:

If $Y_i$, where $i=1,2,3,...$ be $r$-sections of a set $X$, so are $\cup_iY_i$ and $\cap_iY_i$.

A subset $Y\subset X$ is an $r$-section of $X$ iff the relation $r$ well orders $X$ and there is no $u\in (X-Y)$ such that $u\ r\ v$ for any $v\in Y$.

Using the definition alone the theorem appears logically obvious. A formal proof I leave on the author.